# How could i restart my game? Tabs, jQuery, game

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need to make an invisible background color that appears after 10 seconds of losing a game. In the finish, I also should make a button "Restart" that restarts the game.

Please, help me!

I have found some information about restarting on the internet, but I couldn't understand most of this, so please may you explain to me a very simple method? I am just a student, it totally fits me more than difficult theories.

```
const width = $(document).width() - 200 // ширина окна html 1366
const height = $(document).height() - 200 // высота окна html 600
let timer = 10
let points = 0
let isClick = false
let intervalID

$('.item-1').click(function () {
    setRandomPosition()
    $('.points').text(points)
    points += 10
    if(points == 100) { 
        endGame('Вы выиграли')
        clearInterval(intervalID)
    }
})
let intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    if(timer > 0) {
        timer--
        $('.timer').text(timer)
    } else {
        endGame('Вы проиграли')
        
    }
}, 1000)
function setRandomPosition() {
    $('.item-1').css({
        'top' : Math.floor(Math.random() * height),
        'left' : Math.floor(Math.random() * width)
    })
}
function endGame(endText) {
    $('.end').css('display', 'flex')
    $('h1').text(endText)
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.item {
    width: 200px;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    background-color: lightpink;
    position: absolute;
}
.timer {
    font-size: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.points {
    font-size: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.end {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.restart {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="item item-1"></div>
    <p class="timer">10</p>
    <p class="points">0</p>
    <div class="end">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to know how you want the game to reset since you haven't include information about how it should reset, but here is an example:

```
$('.end h1').click(function() {
  points = 0;
  $('.points').text(points);
  timer = 10;
  intervalID = setInterval(_timer, 1000)
});
```

Also I've moved your code a bit around, but nothing major.

**Demo**

```js
const width = $(document).width(); - 200 // ширина окна html 1366
const height = $(document).height(); - 200 // высота окна html 600
let timer = 10;
let points = 0;
let isClick = false;
let intervalID;

$('.item-1').click(function() {
  setRandomPosition()
  points += 10
  $('.points').text(points)
  if (points == 100) {
    endGame('Вы выиграли')
    clearInterval(intervalID)
  }
})

function _timer() {
  $('.end').css('display', 'none')
  if (timer > 0) {
    timer--
    $('.timer').text(timer)
  } else {
    endGame('Вы проиграли')

  }
};

intervalID = setInterval(_timer, 1000)

function setRandomPosition() {
  $('.item-1').css({
    'top': Math.floor(Math.random() * height),
    'left': Math.floor(Math.random() * width)
  })
}

$('.end h1').click(function() {
  points = 0;
  $('.points').text(points);
  timer = 10;
  intervalID = setInterval(_timer, 1000)
});

function endGame(endText) {
  $('.end').css('display', 'flex')
  $('h1').text(endText)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: lightpink;
  position: absolute;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.points {
  font-size: 65px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.end {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.restart {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <p class="timer">10</p>
  <p class="points">0</p>
  <div class="end">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```